# Bootstrap push and pull Not working properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, push, pull

I m Using Bootstrap push and pull which is not working properly !
Mobile View is Working Properly But Web View Is shifted to Left
A Help will be greatly appreciated

Here is my Code not working properly ----

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="Style/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="Header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 HeadLeft">
                    STATUS 99
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 HeadRight">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FB Scrap</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SMS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-2 LeftMenu">
                <h4>FB Status Categories</h4>
                <div class="sidebar-nav">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <span class="visible-xs navbar-brand">Sidebar menu</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Reviews <span class="badge">1,118</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-push-2 RightMenu">
                <h4>FB Cover pictures</h4>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                    <li>Funny Status</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-pull-8">
                <h1>Main Content</h1>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS I M USING

```
body {
font-family:Tahoma;
}

.Header{
background-color:rgb(59,89,152);
min-height:3em;
color:white;
}

.HeadLeft{
font-family:'Times New Roman';
font-size:2.2em;
padding:0.1em;
}

.HeadRight{
font-family:Tahoma;
font-size:1.25em;
padding:0.1em;

}

.HeadRight a{
text-decoration:none;
color:rgb(255,255, 255);    
}

.LeftMenu{
box-shadow: 0 0.6250em 0.3125em #888888;
}

.LeftMenu h4{
background-color:rgb(240, 240, 240);
/*padding:0.1em 0;*/
}

.RightMenu{
box-shadow: 0 0.6250em 0.3125em #888888;
}

.RightMenu h4{
background-color:rgb(240, 240, 240);
/*padding:0.1em 0;*/
}

ul li{
/*padding:0.2em;*/
}

/* make sidebar nav vertical */ 
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.sidebar-nav .navbar .navbar-collapse {
padding: 0;
max-height: none;
}
.sidebar-nav .navbar ul {
float: none;
display: block;
}
.sidebar-nav .navbar li {
float: none;
display: block;
}
.sidebar-nav .navbar li a {
padding-top: 12px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your HTML structure like this,

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="Header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 HeadLeft">
                        STATUS 99
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 HeadRight">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">FB Scrap</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">SMS</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 LeftMenu">
                    <h4>FB Status Categories</h4>
                    <div class="sidebar-nav">
                        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <span class="visible-xs navbar-brand">Sidebar menu</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reviews <span class="badge">1,118</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-push-8 RightMenu">
                    <h4>FB Cover pictures</h4>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                        <li>Funny Status</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-pull-2">
                    <h1>Main Content</h1>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**The thing is Bootstrap `col-` classes always come from left. So the left menu need to have just `col-lg-2` which will take the width of 2 bootstrap columns. Then you have to give width to your right menu, so you give `col-md-2` to it. Then you have to push it to the right side using `col-push`. Bootstrap has a 12 column layout. So you could give a `col-lg-8` for the main content. And then you have to pull it back 2 columns since it is going to start rendering after the RightMenu according to our HTML structure**

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 LeftMenu">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-push-8 RightMenu">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-pull-2">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Your logic in using push/pull was just a bit off. You need to push the second column eight column widths to the right (to make room for the eight column width column.) Then you need to pull the third column two column widths to the left (to make room for the two column width .RightMenu column.) You should read through the BootStrap docs again. The pushing/pulling occurs relative to where the column would normally render. It's a bit tricky to wrap your head around at first.